# Memory throughput for strided memory accesses

Tags: x86-64, cpu-architecture, memory-bandwidth

I am measuring memory throughput and runtimes using `_mm256_i32gather_epi32` intrinsic. Here is the loop I use for testing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i+=8) {
    const __m256i* indexes_2 = reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(indexes_ptr + i);
    __m256i index_reg = _mm256_loadu_si256(indexes_2);
    __m256i values = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(data_ptr, index_reg, 4);
    sum = _mm256_add_epi32(sum, values);
}
```

I use the index array (specified through `indexes_ptr`) to change the access pattern into `data_ptr` array. The `data_ptr` array is 256 MB in size, so everything misses the caches. Here are possible values for indexes_ptr:

- sequential - 0, 1, 2, 3, etc
- stride 4 - 0, 4, 8, 12
- stride 16 - 0, 16, 32, 48, etc
- stride 32
- stride 64
- stride 128

So, the intrinsic `_mm256_i32gather_epi32` will load 8 values. In my system, the size of a cache line is 64 bytes, so:

- sequential touches one cache line
- stride 4 touches two cache lines
- stride 16 touches eight cache lines
- stride 64 touches eight cache lines
- stride 128 touches eight cache lines

My expectations is that the stride 16, 64 and 128 will have similar runtimes and memory throughputs. This is however not the case. Here are the numbers:

- sequential, 0.13 s, 16828.2607 MB/s
- strided 4, 0.07 s, 17246.1914 MB/s
- strided 16, 0.918406, 5205.1085 MB/s
- strided 32, 1.650566s, 4756.5279 MB/s
- stride 64, 1.798604, 5440.2228 MB/s
- stride 128, 2.186620, 4672.1329 MB/s

Where does the difference between stride 16, 32, 64 and 128 come from, since they all are accessing exactly 8 cache lines in each instructions?

Comment: Possible spatial prefetching pulling in useless cache lines?  Unlikely when demands loads are using up all memory bandwidth.  Maybe L2 streamer prefetch working better for strides that aren't too big, so it doesn't get to the end of a page and have to start over as often.

Comment: None of that explains the boost for stride 64; that might be an anomaly.  Perhaps something with L3 hashed indexing?  If your stride is big enough, you don't touch all of your 256 MiB, so you could maybe start to get some L3 hits, especially if the adaptive replacement policy (https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/) helps any.  Those are just my initial wild guesses, though.

Comment: What CPU and DRAM?  e.g. my system is an i7-6700k with DDR4-2666

Comment: Cache conflict misses could increasingly be a problem for L1 and L2 caches as the stride increases; they use "normal" indexing, so for example two addresses 4096 bytes apart go in the same set in L1d cache.  But if you're only loading once from each line, demand misses can't get evicted from L1d before they're used, I expect; they should satisfy a demand load as the data arrives.  The L2 streamer can lock on to strided access patterns, though, so that is prefetch.

Comment: Link to the test: https://github.com/ibogosavljevic/johnysswlab/blob/master/2022-07-memproperties/memory_throughput.cpp

Compile with: 
clang++ -g -O3 -mavx2 -DLIKWID_PERFMON memory_throughput.cpp -o memory_throughput -llikwid
Run with:
likwid-perfctr -C 0 -g MEM -m ./memory_throughput

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz

Comment: Peter, you're the best!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245946/discussion-between-bogi-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: I did measurements with huge pages enabled, same thing. Here are the numbers:
stride 4, 0.077334 s
stride 16, 0.952457 s
stride 32, 0.959871 s
stride 64, 1.114981 s
stride 128, 0.764569 s